# In Grails, how can I get a ConfigObject of messages.properties for locale?

Tags: java, grails, internationalization, groovy

In Grails, I would like to get a [ConfigObject](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigObject.html) reference to the loaded messages properties file for the current locale. Or some way to easily read in the messages properties (for the current locale) in it's entirety. I want to convert it to JSON and send it back to the client to be used to lookup strings via javascript.

In essence I want to do something like this:

```
def props = new java.util.Properties()
props.load(... the right message bundle ...);
def messages = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)
render messages as JSON
```

I'm assuming there's a more graceful way to do this. The messageSource interface only allows you to get a message for a particular key. I want the entire resource bundle so I can convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workable solution of just loading the properties directly from the proper messages properties bundle based on the current locale.

It looks like I can just load the file with a path relative to the root of the application. This worked for running locally both with the embedded tomcat and as a war ('grails run-app' and 'grails run-war') but I haven't tested deployed to a container to know if the path will be resolved properly.

Here's my test controller:

```
import grails.converters.*
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder as LCH 

class I18nController {

    def index = {
        def locale = LCH.getLocale().toString();
        def langSuffix = ( locale == "en" ) ? "" : "_${locale}" 
        def props = new java.util.Properties()
        props.load( new FileInputStream( "grails-app/i18n/messages${langSuffix}.properties" ) )
        render ( new ConfigSlurper().parse(props) ) as JSON
    }

}
```

Can be accessed like:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/i18n
http://localhost:8080/myapp/i18n?lang=es
http://localhost:8080/myapp/i18n?lang=en
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is right? I'd expect to see `params.lang` referenced somewhere within the `index` closure

Comment: the call to the LocaleContextHolder takes that into account already

Comment: This still works in Grails 2.5.3  Needed this to pass messages to `angular-translate` plugin which can use an endpoint to async load messages based on a language code

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came here looking to do the exact same thing. Using `LocaleContextHolder` to get the desired locale is a good starting point, although I decided to use `RequestContextUtils`. In my implementation, I wanted to use java's own locale resolution strategy. So here goes (currently using grails 2.1.2):

```
// Controller
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils
import grails.converters.JSON


class I18nController {
    def strings() {
    ResourceBundle clientMessages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.ClientMessages",
        RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request),
        Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader)
    render clientMessages as JSON
    }
}
```

When you serialize this thing using the default JSON marshaller, it's not what you want. So add this to your `BootStrap.groovy` inside the `init` closure:

```
    // JSON Marshaller to serialize ResourceBundle to string table.
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(ResourceBundle) { bundle ->
        def returnObject = [:]
        bundle.keys.each {
            returnObject."${it}" = bundle.getString(it)
        }
        returnObject
    }
```

And finally, put the resources you want to send to the javascript client side in your classpath. In my example, these would go in src/java/com/example/ClientMessages.properties.

```
size.small=Small
size.wide=Wide
size.large=Large
```

In the client, going to `myapp/i18n/strings` you will see the JSON like this:

```
{"size.small":"Small","size.wide":"Wide","size.large":"Large"}
```

So with this solution, you put all and only the strings you want to send to the javascript side for lookup, and put everything else in the grails i18n folder. One caveat is that the strings here are not available to g:message and vice versa. If anyone can figure out a solution to single out one basename in i18n for this purpose, I'd like to see it.

Answer (score -1):

The implementation type of `MessageSource` is [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/context/support/PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.html). Perhaps there are methods on this class (or one of it's parents), that will allow you to get a reference to the entire set of `Properties`.

The following looks like it might work (though I haven't tested it):

```
// Get a reference to the message Source either via dependency injection or looking-up
// the bean in the application context
def messageSource
Properties messages = messageSource.getProperties("messages.properties").properties
// Now convert the Properties instance to JSON using your favorite Java-JSON library
```

This is not a great solution as the `getProperties(filename)` method is protected, so you should not be able to call it, but you can because of a bug in Groovy. It also makes some implicit assumptions about the implementation type of `mesageSource`.

Comment: like you said, it's probably not the best solution since you are making blind assumptions of the implementation behind the interface. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: agreed, but sometimes you have to sacrifice some OO purity in order to get things done